# Помогите с пунктуацией в предложении

Tags: пунктуация

> Когда холод  для тебя еще не повод прятать платья.

Comment: Это законченное предложение? Можете показать контекст, чтобы было понятней?

Answer (score 1):

Здесь вот какая особенность: если между подлежащим и именной частью сказуемого находится служебное слово (союз, частица), вводное слово, а также дополнение или обстоятельство, **отнесенное ко всему предложению** (а не входящее в состав подлежащего или сказуемого), то пауза не делается и тире не ставится (пауза как бы заполняется одним из перечисленных слов).
В этом случае общее слово выступает в качестве разделителя между подлежащим и сказуемым.

Наречие или дополнение, отнесенное ко всему предложению:

Необдуманный поступок **вообще** шаг опасный.

Литература **всегда** учебник жизни.

Это спокойствие **часто** признак великой, хотя скрытой силы.

Туризм **для меня** лучший отдых.

Стихи **для вас** одна забава.

Отец **у меня** золотой человек.

*Когда холод **для тебя еще** не повод прятать платья.*

Я думаю, здесь как раз такой случай: **для тебя** относится ко всему предложению, следовательно, тире нет.

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из того, что можно понять в отсутствие контекста, ответ таков.
Выделим основу: *Холод не повод прятать платья*. По общему правилу, тире между подлежащим и сказуемым не ставится, если стоит частица *не* (пример: *Бедность не порок*). Но из этого правила есть исключения, обсуждать которые в отсутствие контекста мне бы не хотелось.